# Hangfire recurring job at a specific time ASP MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, hangfire

Ive been recently using hangfire to process lengthy jobs enabling me to return API calls more efficiently within an ASP MVC Core application.

i have implimented this by adding the following to startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()));
        services.AddHangfire(configuration => configuration.UseSqlServerStorage(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseCors("AllowAll");

        app.UseMvc();

        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        app.UseHangfireServer();     
    }
```

and then calling this within an action on a controller

```
  using (new BackgroundJobServer())
                    {
                        formData.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
                        formData.Source = "Web";
                        formData.StatusItem =  _context.Status.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Default == true);

                        _context.Lead.Add(formData);
                        _context.SaveChanges();
                    }
```

Now i have a need to send a an email at 1am every day with the status of records from the database.

Im slightly confused on the implementation from the following perspective:

-Where do i implement the background job?
-Do i put the call in a method, if so how is this called/
-I cannot find BackgroundJob.AddOrUpdate, which i understand is used for the recurring tasks
-The schedule method takes a timespan object, but all examples are using CRON.

I have all the code to create the email, i just need help scheduling it

Thanks for your help  in advance.

Comment: Have you read this page http://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/background-methods/performing-recurrent-tasks.html ?